# Making console options required with signature syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I want to make a console argument "required" in Laravel 5.2 I simply do: `{someArg}`

How do I make an option "required" using the console command signature syntax in 5.2?

Nothing seems to be mentioned in the docs.

For instance, here is current signature:

```
booking:make
{account : Account ID that owns it.}
{--name=* : Booking names this can be found under.}
{--user=* : Any users that have access.}
{--status=active : If the account should be active to start.}
```

In the above example, how would I make the `--user` and `--name` options required? There needs to be at least one value for each of those options. Currently, I check this with a simple IF THEN. In older commands before the new signature syntax I used `InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED`.

Comment: Can you give an example of *argument* and *option* and example of the command you want to make?

Comment: @TheFallen added an example to clarify.

Comment: I think the idea of the options is to be optional by default, so you'll have to check if no option provided to output an error and return.

Answer (score -1):

All arguments you define in command's signature are **required by default**.

This is a signature with a required user argument:

```
protected $signature = 'email:send {user}';
```

If you wanted to make user argument optional, you'd need to do:

```
protected $signature = 'email:send {user?}';
```

You can also provide default values the following way:

```
protected $signature = 'email:send {user=bob}';
```

You'll find above examples and some more details in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#command-io

Comment: I already know how to make console arguments required. This is a question about doing the same with console options. I've added extra details to help clarify.